# How add top-header above main menu?

Tags: magento2, header

How can I add top-header above main menu?

I need top-header with text above main menu

Answer (score 2):

In magento2, you can change the position of a container using the [`move`](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv)  tag

Create `default.xml` at **`app/design/frontend/{YourThemevendor}/{Themename}/Magento_Theme/layout/`**
and add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">  
    <body>
    <move element="header.panel.wrapper" destination="page.top" before="navigation.sections"/>  
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Where should I add this code?